# Maven Javadoc Plugin - override specific part of default CSS

Tags: java, maven, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm using Maven Javadoc plugin with default CSS. I want to override a specific part of default styling. However if I specify a custom css file using `<stylesheetfile>` tag it overrides default CSS.

What I want is the default and custom CSS to be applied together. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#stylesheetfile) `-stylesheetfile <path>`, you can only supply one css file, you can try merging Java provided default [stylesheet.css](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/stylesheet.css) with yours and try.

Comment: I already did the merging way. I just wanted to know if there was a way to specify just the styling you want to override.

Comment: No you can't override.